# Помогите разобраться с указателями при передаче массива из класса

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, объекты

изучаю С++, для программы нужно в рамках класса объединить блок данных и его описание. Нужно при обращении к классу вытянуть массив, и вот тут начинается беда и танцы с бубном, компилятор выдает целый ворох ошибок, при этом при обращении к остальным членам класса проблем нет.

```
class FONT {
public:
    int FONT_ARRAY[12][20] =
    {
        {0x00, 0x00, 0xFC, 0x3F, 0xFE, 0x7F, 0x07, 0xE0, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x07, 0xE0, 0xFE, 0x7F, 0xFC, 0x3F},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0xE0, 0x0E, 0xF0, 0x07, 0xF8, 0x03, 0xDC, 0x03, 0xCE, 0x03, 0xC7, 0x87, 0xC3, 0xFE, 0xC1, 0xFC, 0xC0},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x30, 0x0E, 0x70, 0x07, 0xE0, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x03, 0xC0, 0x83, 0xC1, 0xC7, 0xE3, 0xFE, 0x7F, 0x7C, 0x3E},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x01, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x80, 0x01, 0x80, 0x01, 0x80, 0x01, 0x80, 0x01, 0x80, 0x01, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x30, 0xFF, 0x70, 0xC3, 0xE0, 0xC3, 0xC0, 0xC3, 0xC0, 0xC3, 0xC0, 0xC3, 0xE1, 0x83, 0x7F, 0x03, 0x3F},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0xFC, 0x3F, 0xFE, 0x7F, 0x87, 0xE1, 0x83, 0xC1, 0x83, 0xC1, 0x83, 0xC1, 0x87, 0xE3, 0x0E, 0x7F, 0x0C, 0x3E},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0xFF, 0x83, 0xFF, 0xC3, 0x01, 0xE3, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x00, 0x3F, 0x00},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0x7C, 0x3E, 0xFE, 0x7F, 0xC7, 0xE3, 0x83, 0xC1, 0x83, 0xC1, 0x83, 0xC1, 0xC7, 0xE3, 0xFE, 0x7F, 0x7C, 0x3E},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0x7C, 0x30, 0xFE, 0x70, 0xC7, 0xE1, 0x83, 0xC1, 0x83, 0xC1, 0x83, 0xC1, 0xC7, 0xE1, 0xFE, 0x7F, 0xFC, 0x3F},
        {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x30, 0x0C, 0x30, 0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00},
        {0x0B, 0x14, 0x30, 0x10, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}
    };
    int FONT_WIDTH = 20;
    int FONT_START_CHAR = 48;
    int FONT_CHAR_WIDTH = 10;
    int FONT_CHAR_HEIGHT = 16;
};

int main()
{
    FONT a;
    FONT *p = &a;
    int f = p->FONT_ARRAY;
    std::cout << f[0][5] << "\n";
}
```

В строке 3 ошибка

> Ошибка C2864   "FONT::FONT_ARRAY": статический элемент элемент данных с инициализатором внутри класса должен иметь неизменяемый целочисленный константный тип или должен быть указан как "inline"

В строке 28

> Ошибка C2440   инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "int [12][20]" в "int"

В строке 29

> Ошибка C2109   для индекса требуется массив или указатель

Буду признателен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И как вы себе представляете применение индексов к целому числу?

```
int f = p->FONT_ARRAY;
std::cout << f[0][5] << "\n";
```

Что такое, например, `6[4][8]`? :)

Попробуйте так:

```
int f = p->FONT_ARRAY[0][5];
std::cout << f << "\n";
```

Comment: Получилось, спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Здесь спасибо имеет вид принятого ответа (птичка слева).

Comment: Обязательно! Может еще подскажете, есть ли возможность передавать ссылку на класс в параметрах функции, не указывая имя самого класса? Я имею ввиду универсальную функцию, которой можно "скормить" любой класс?

Comment: К примеру вместо явного указания класса CLASS в функции foo указать псевдоним, который передаст настоящее имя класса из параметров при вызове функции.

Comment: Представим, что это возможно. Как именно вы собираетесь сказать функции, что именно она должна делать с классом? Просто от этого зависит решение, которое можно предложить взамен...

Comment: Harry, не буду тянуть кота за хвост, я бы хотел создать универсальную процедуру для вывода текста, это для микроконтроллера, в параметрах при вызове этой процедуры, помимо координат передается так же и имя шрифта, а их некоторое кол-во. Или, как вариант, создать дополнительную функцию SetFont, как в некоторых ЯП, тогда можно обойтись и без дополнительного параметра.

Comment: Ну тогда по имени шрифта ищете сам шрифт и используете — зачем вам передача ссылки на класс, не указывая **имя класса**? Класс-то один и тот же?

Comment: То есть, как вариант внутри процедуры условный swich case, где по имени шрифта выбирается нужный класс с шрифтом? Классов несколько, столько, сколько шрифтов.

Comment: Вы хотите передавать именно строкой с именем? организуйте какой-то поиск по имени, `switch`, конечно, вариант, но плохо расширяемый. Но можно просто передавать имя переменной класса, содержащей шрифт. Так ли уж важно, писать `...,"Serif",...` или `...,Serif,...`?

Comment: Понял, Harry, еще раз огромное спасибо за помощь!!!)